# Navigate to Jquery tab onclick of button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery Tabs with jquery-ui 1.9.2. I want to go to another tab2 on click of submit button in tab1.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() { 
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", "Page2");
    });
```

It is giving me

```
cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
```

Similar error on using select.I also used index as in another post.Same error. My code for tabs is like this :

```
<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="page1.jsp">Page1</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.jsp">Page2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT

The href I have given are actually JSP's.The tabs come out fine but the switch to another tab doesn't work

Please help. What initialization is this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
```

instead of:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", "Page2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
// Activate the second tab (zero-based index)
$("#tabs ul").tabs( "select", 1 );
```

using New API:

```
// Activate the second panel
$("#tabs ul").tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

Comment: @SKaul:updated the answer. Check now. remove id selector

Comment: Why would this work ? I did try it though, it doesn't work and gives me no error.

Comment: @SKaul:can you check Now??

Comment: Strange. can you create fiddle for same??

Comment: It is working with divs as tab. How do I create seperate pages on fiddle to specify for HREF

Comment: I am not using divs as tabs content but jsp pages, the javascript functions are referenced in the jsp page. I have used alert there which works fine but tabs() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
```

- The index starts from 0 so to goto tab 2 give in 1.

Let me know if this works or if you have any more queries.

Here is the full html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="../JS/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });

        function goto() {

            $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 1);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">0</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>
                1
                <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="goto()" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>
                2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>
                3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SKaul: give in the index of the tab and not the ID

Comment: @SKaul: have given in the full html. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried creating a seperate function with onclick, it didn't work, the same error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. How do you want me to call the tabs ? I already do have the $().click in document.ready()

Comment: I am not using divs as tabs content but jsp pages, the javascript functions are referenced in the jsp page. I have used alert there which works fine but tabs() doesn't work.

Comment: @SKaul: it has to be a # link to get the tabs working